# Image caching with NodeJs and Redis

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis

I'm trying to cache recent files (mostly images) in Redis. When I read file from redis, it seems that some kind of corruption or something happens that I can download the image as before but it is not visible. The interesting part of it is that when I read the file from redis, it's size is about the double. I don't understand what is happening here.
Here is what I implemented:

```
import express from 'express';
import { Redis } from 'ioredis';
import fs from 'fs';
import { Readable } from 'node:stream'

const redis = new Redis();
const app = express();
const key = 'theKey';

app.get('', async (req, res) => {
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="image.png"`,
    });

    const file = fs.createReadStream('./image.png');

    const cached = await redis.getBuffer(key);

    if (cached) {
        const file = Readable.from(cached);
        file.pipe(res);
    } else {
        await cacher(file);
        file.pipe(res);
    }
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running on 3000'))


async function cacher(readable) {
    const buffer = [];
    readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
        buffer.push(chunk);
    })
    readable.on('end', () => {
        const mergedBuffers = buffer.join();
        const buf = Buffer.from(mergedBuffers);
        redis.setBuffer(key, buf);
        redis.expire(key, 5)
    })
}
```

**update**: I solved the issue. The correct implementation is to use `Buffer.concat()` instead of `join()` method. So Here is my updated cacher function:

```
async function cacher(readable) {
    const bufferArr = []
    readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
        bufferArr.push(chunk)
    })
    readable.on('end', () => {
        redis.setBuffer(key, Buffer.concat(bufferArr));
        redis.expire(key, 5)
    })

}
```